# How to stop at last image using View Pager Gallery

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-gallery

Hi I am using a android Gallery view with View Pager. The problem is that, when we slide the images in the gallery, after the last image, the gallery starts showing the images from the first in the list of images in the gallery. what I need is, when by sliding the images in the gallery if I reach at the last image, then again sliding the image, it should stop there itself as in the case of List view, and should go to the first image in the list.

Any help can be useful, and Appriciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Any help can be useful, and also any code brother!!

Comment: @mmlooloo are you asking me any help? or do you want me to make changes in question???

Comment: yes you asked in your question that any help can be useful and i asked in the comment that any code you tried can be useful for us ;-)

Answer (score 0):

getcount() method in adapter should return the image count. Then it will stop at last image in adapter.

Comment: How to stop at the last image? with the image count, could you explain it? If i swipe on the last image how will it not show me the first image?

Comment: In my case it is always stopping on the last image of view pager.